# Deactivating site collection feature on MySite

Tags: sharepoint, mysite

We have a custom master page that is deployed to the MySite web application per these instructions - 
http://www.sharepointblog.com/2008/07/sp2007-custom-master-pages-on-subsites.html

However, we require the ability to deactivate the feature on all the site collections that are within the MySite webapplication. The feature is built as a site collection scope. How would we deactivate them on an application that has potentially 3000+ MySites?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would build a simple console application which iterates over all site collections (MySites) of your web application and deactivates the feature. You'll have to run this piece of code with elevate privileges ([SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsecurity.runwithelevatedprivileges.aspx)) so you have the permission to deactivate a site collection feature.

```
private static void DeleteWebsiteCollections()
        {
            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
            {
                SPWebApplication webApp = SPWebApplication.Lookup(new Uri("http://MySiteHostWebApp"));
                SPSiteCollection mySites = webApp.Sites;

                foreach (SPSite site in mySites)
                {
                    site.Features.Remove(new Guid("place your feature id here"));

                    if (null != site)
                    {
                        site.Dispose();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: This is pretty much exactly how we did it, only I wrapped it in a feature which was deployed to the My Site web application. When the feature deactivated, we used the above code to remove the feature. Thanks Flo!

Answer (score 0):

This code can be stapled into the masterpage too.
Only site.Features.Remove(new Guid("place your feature id here")); should remain.